# Conversion failed when converting datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to display a date field as just 'Jan' so a 3 letter abbreviation.

I am trying

```
try_convert(char(3),Datename(Month,[Date]))
```

But i am getting 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string'

I understand this is because the date is stored as a varchar but it displays as dd-mm-yyyy 12:53:34:300.

Is there anyway i can display the month abbreviation from the date without changing the date field from varchar to date.

Thanks

Comment: Does this help you - `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(3), [Date], 100) as MonthName`

Comment: _Column_, not field...

Comment: Fix your data so you are storing dates as dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better question, here, is why are you storing your dates as a `varchar`. **Don't**. There are SO many reasons why you shouldn't, and I honestly don't know any good ones for why you should.

As a quick example, the "date" `'31-01-2000'` is **after** the date `'09-12-2017'` in `varchar` terms. So a query with `WHERE [varcharDateColumn] <= '09-12-2017'` won't return items from the first above date. you'd therefore have to use a `CONVERT`/`CAST`, which means you can't use any indexes you have.

For what you have, the correct code will (likely) be :

```
LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,TRY_CONVERT(date,[Date])),3)
```

However, I strongly suggest you fix your datatypes, then there is no need for the use of the `TRY_CONVERT`.

Answer (score 0):

A slight change in your query can help you. Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(3),Datename(Month,CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR(20))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL Server 2012+.. you can use FORMAT function.. Are you your date column has valid dates..if not you can use ISDate() function to validate them..

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MMM')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Jan
```

Comment: `FORMAT` is helpful, however, it is very slow. You'll find that something like `LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, YourColumn))` will massively out perform a query using `FORMAT`.

Comment: @Larnu "FORMAT is helpful, however, it is very slow"- True that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
--successfully converts date in dd-mm-yyyy fromat, stored as string
select parse('29-12-2017' as date using 'en-GB')
--displays three-letter abbreviation of month
select FORMAT(parse('29-12-2017' as date using 'en-GB'), 'MMM') --> will return Dec
```

So, just replace passed string `'29-12-2017'` with your column name and it should work :)

NOTE: `PARSE` function is available in SQL Server 2012 onwards.

Comment: 'Error converting string value '10' into data type date using culture 'en-GB'

Comment: `10`? You said that the format is `dd-mm-yyyy`. What kind of date format is `10`?

Comment: sorry, the actual format is dd-mm-yyyy 00:00:00:000

Comment: It converts such formats as well. `10` is none of these formats... Is a day? Maybe a month? Or an hour?